# Where does jdo data go while running a war google appengine app in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, jdo

I'm using eclipse and google appengine plugin to develop a war app. I'm trying to use JDO persistency (per appengine rules). I'd like to be able to inspect, add and remove jdo objects my app uses. Is that possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While running locally, http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin provides a administration interface.

Answer (score 0):

Select "Datastore Viewer" from the dashboard at https://appengine.google.com/.

Comment: I meant during development, locally in my computer.